# How can I identify if my page is rendered in a normal browser or SAP CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER

Tags: javascript, browser, abap

I'm working on a demonstration that simulates a mobile device with touch events, so pinch zoom, or scroll events on a desktop browser's touch events. So far I've got it working in Chrome, IE, and Firefox.

The final requirement is that the same code must also run from inside the SAP `CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER` class. This class basically is recognized as IE at least when it is ran on Windows.

My problem is that for whatever reason the `CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER` does not support actual browser events like `pointerdown` or `pointermove` like they do in IE

So I want to be able to attempt to identify if the page is rendered in IE, or SAP. However, since SAP uses IE my javascript always says it is IE.

Is there a specific way I could identify the difference?

Just to clarify how the webpage is loaded inside the SAP GUI. I'm calling the method `show_url( url = myurl in_place = 'X' ).` for my instance of the `CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER`. So my ABAP looks like this basically:

```
data: g_html_view type ref to CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER,
      g_custom_container type ref to CL_GUI_DOCKING_CONTAINER,
      edurl(1024) value 'http://localhost:8080/MyPage.html'.

if g_custom_container is initial.
    create object g_custom_container
        exporting
            extension = 3000.
endif.
if g_html_view is initial.
    create object g_html_view
        exporting
            parent = g_custom_container.
endif.
call method g_html_view->show_url( url = edurl in_place = 'X' ).
```

Comment: Detect the feature instead?  E.g. `if ("pointerdown" in window) ...`

Comment: @AlexK. Funny enough even though the `CL_HTML_VIEWER` doesn't support it, this would still return `true`. This was one of my first attempts to  get this to work.

Comment: Anything unique in navigator.userAgent ?

Comment: @AlexK. Ah! Hadn't thought of that. Looks like there is a difference between the two. Basically in standard IE the word `touch` is present but in the `CL_HTML_VIEWER` class the output of `navigator.userAgent` is different. That gives me a place to look further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try any one of the following:

```
>>> window.is_sap_gui
true

>>> window.sapHtmlControl
"TRUE"

>>> window.location.protocol
"sapr3:"
```

We use the first option, but that one may be one we have defined explicitly in our framework. The Second is one SAP is probably setting.

Failing either of these, the best way is to check the protocol. It will be a dead giveaway.

Comment: Sorry @Marius I tried all of your suggestions from inside the SAP GUI html viewer and the responses were either `undefined` or for the last one `http:` None of the values you mentioned appeared.

Comment: @JRSofty , ah, then I assume you are not loading the pages inside SAP using the `LOAD_DATA` methods (using either MIME objects in SAP or just table data), but opening up an external page web page.

Comment: @JRSofty, you could either 1) perhaps consider starting your browsing using static page content that just redirect to the web page, or 2) you can catch the `hdl_on_load_complete` or some navigate event and do a javascript call (subclassing the html class is required for this) to set a flag in the DOM. This last approach would only expose this after DOM initialization however.

Comment: Hi @Marius, sorry if I didn't give you enough information to work with. I've included the ABAP code (not exactly formatted this way but it's basically the same) that I use to load the web page in the SAP GUI. In this case behind the ABAP there's also a screen with a custom control. I hope this clarifies things a bit. The page needs to know if the SAP GUI is loading the page or if it's opening in a different IE type browser. Currently I'm only able to catch the IE version but that's not always the best way.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me:

```
window.sapHtmlControl
```

- "TRUE"      if document is embebed in CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER on a Dynpro in SAP GUI
- "Undefined" if document is in Egde/chrome